# Google IDE cookie not removed by shopware cookie manager

Tags: cookies, shopware

i just don't understand, why SW 5.6.3 and above is not removing a remarketing cookie.
I use the shopware doc example code from https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/cookie-consent-manager/

```
public function addComfortCookie(): CookieCollection
{
    $pluginNamespace = $this->container->get('snippets')->getNamespace('consenttool');
    $collection = new CookieCollection();
    $collection->add(new CookieStruct(
        'wolfAllowRemarketing',
        '/^IDE/',
        $pluginNamespace->get('remarketing_cookie_label'),
        CookieGroupStruct::STATISTICS
    ));
    return $collection;
}
```

The cookie is listed in the configuration of the consent manager. At the first visit no cookies are set, after disallow all the "IDE" cookie is always set.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this cookie in same domain?

Comment: It´s from .doubleclick.net

Answer (score 1):

The Cookie Consent Manager can remove only from the current domain. So it can't delete third party cookies. You can only include the external script by optin like the Shopware Google Analytics plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then Shopware should add this note to the developer guide...